# JSON.loads is converting double quotes to single quotes

Tags: python, json

I am beginner to Python. Here I am trying use JSON.load to parse the JSON string. When using json.dumps, I receive the following output:

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "sourceip": "10.10.10.1",
      "destinationip": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    {
      "sourceip": "10.10.10.2",
      "destinationip": "127.0.0.1"
    }
 ]
}
```

I am applying json.loads function on this to use them later for another function. However when using json.loads on the results it replaces all the double quotes with single quote like below:

```
{'events': [{'sourceip': '10.10.10.1', 'destinationip': '127.0.0.1'}, {'sourceip': '10.10.10.2', 'destinationip': '127.0.0.1'}]}
```

How can I use json.loads without getting the double quotes replaced with single quotes.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you a need a double quotes in a loaded object ? There's no reason for wanting that. In `python`, `"x"` and `'x'` are equal. That is `"x" == 'x'`

Comment: Can i know why do u need to convert this single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: JSON _requires_ double quotes around keys and strings; once the JSON has been loaded into a Python object, there is no such requirement.  By default, Python displays strings as single-quoted.  There is no problem here; were you to dump the python object back to JSON you would see double quotes again.

Comment: I will need to convert the json to CSV later, when using the panda module it gives an error that is Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes. Therefore I need double quotes.

Comment: @SaisivaA I need double quotes for converting this to a CSV using panda module and when using the module it requires the object to be in double quotes.

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion that property name is expected in double quotes?

Comment: Why do you need converts from single quotes into double quotes..?

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari When I write the output of json.loads to a file and use panda module to convert this to csv. The error I receive is "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)". As soon as I replace the single quotes with double quotes, it happily converts this.

Comment: For the json decode you should pass  a json pass it using `json.dumps(JSON_LOADS_OBJ)`

Comment: Before sending to csv, convert it with double quotes using json.dumps

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari Thanks. I am passing the json object as you have said, e.g. 
search_results_json = search_results.json()
search_results_str = json.dumps(search_results_json, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)

Answer (score 4):

Once you load JSON with `.load` or `.loads`, there are no longer any quotes whatsoever. Instead, it's converted into a data structure consisting of Python objects: the root `dict`, containing other `dict`s or `list`s an so on.

What you see in your second quote is a [textual representation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of that data structure that Python can print for you to examine what is in it. The single quotes are just a convention how Python prints strings when generating such a representation, they are not actually a part of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Later I need to use this to convert to a CSV. So when I store this output to a file and use panda module for conversion of data to csv. It complains that it is expecting the properties to be in double quotes but I am not able to achieve that or don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: @guar then do a research on what you are trying to do, and if it comes up empty, ask another question. There, describe what you are trying to do, a [mcve] of what you are doing, what you expect and what you get and what else you tried.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Python to print a dict using double quotes instead of single quotes then? Otherwise that would involve dumping the dict to a string back using, e.g. `json.dumps()` but then you lose the 'structure' of that data.

Comment: @s.k if you need to get machine-readable JSON back, use `dump`/`dumps`. I don't know what "lose the structure" means, JSON is a structured format.